# How to hide a button by using a class function in python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
shape = Canvas(root)

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create_button(self, info, boom, posit):
        self.Button(root)
        self.config(text=info)
        self.bind("<Button-1>",boom)
        self.grid(column=posit[0],row=posit[1])

    def create_label(self, info, posit):
        self.Label(root)
        self.config(text=info)
        self.grid(column=posit[0],row=posit[1])

    def go_away(self):
        print("GO AWAY before")
        self.button.grid_forget()
        print("GO AWAY")

def make_GUI():
    root.title("Hexahexaflexagon")

    hexahexa = GUI()

    quit_butt = GUI()
    quit_butt.create_button("Exit","root.destroy()",[0,1])

    quit_butt.go_away()

make_GUI()
root.mainloop()
```

Okay so I am trying to write a class function to just hide (and if not that then delete) a button created by tkinter, I'm new to classes and the error message I keep getting is that the GUI class does not have that function or that object does not have that attribute, I've tried code such as `frm.forget()`, `.lower()`, `.grid_forget()` but there not working for me.

The traceback is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "N:\HW\Hexahexaflexagon generator.py", line 94, in <module>
      make_GUI()
    File "N:\HW\Hexahexaflexagon generator.py", line 63, in make_GUI
      quit_butt.go_away()
    File "N:\HW\Hexahexaflexagon generator.py", line 51, in go_away
      self.button.grid_forget()
  AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'grid_forget'
```

Comment: Please *fix* the *"wonky indents"*, as part of providing a [mcve] that actually shows the issue.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry I just wanted to get the question up fast

Comment: Could you get the question up *right*, instead? Please give the whole traceback and cut the code down to the minimum necessary.

Comment: Fixed the issue you had

Comment: What are you expecting `self = Button(root)` to do? `self.button` is the method that creates that button, not the button itself - try renaming it to e.g. `def create_button` to make that clearer.

Comment: Good comment and I'll change that now but do you know how to fix the previous issue of hiding the button?

Comment: What do you mean *the previous issue*? Keep fixing the errors until it works - that's programming!

Comment: jonrsharpe just told you how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
self = Button(root)
```

You are redefining `self` from referring to the current object, to now refer to a different object. You have the same problem further down with a label. This is simply not how python works.

You must store the widgets as attributes on `self`, not as `self` itself.

```
self.button = Button(root)
...
self.label = Label(root)
```

Once you do that, you can hide the button or label with `grid_forget` since you're using `grid` to make it visible:

```
self.button.grid_forget()
```

You have another problem in that you're passing in a command as a string. This will not work the way you think it does. If you want to be able to pass in a function, it needs to be a reference to an actual function:

```
quit_butt.button("Exit",root.destroy,[0,1])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes so much sense now, I know about the string function text quit_button, it's just that the command runs and destroys root whenever the button is made so I've made it text just so the program will run and I can fix it later